# Solidity: Call an unimplemented function?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to understand some solidity code, and I see what appears to be the calling of an unimplemented function.

There is an interface defined as:

```
interface IOneInchCaller is ISafeERC20Extension, IGasDiscountExtension {
    struct CallDescription {
        uint256 targetWithMandatory;
        uint256 gasLimit;
        uint256 value;
        bytes data;
    }

    function makeCall(CallDescription memory desc) external;
    function makeCalls(CallDescription[] memory desc) external payable;
}
```

And then elsewhere in the codebase I see a call to this function:

```
function swap(
        IOneInchCaller caller,
        SwapDescription calldata desc,
        IOneInchCaller.CallDescription[] calldata calls
    )
        external
        payable
        whenNotPaused
        returns (uint256 returnAmount)
    {

        caller.makeCalls{value: msg.value}(calls);
```

It is calling the `IOneInchCaller.makeCalls` function, but nowhere is the function implementation defined.  What is going on here?

---

By the way, the code is pulled from [here](https://github.com/1inch-exchange/1inch-v2-contracts/blob/master/contracts/OneInchExchange.sol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making calls to an external contract you don't need the implementation, having the interface is enough.

As example all ERC20 **compliant** tokens use the same interface defined in [EIP-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20). Any contract can interact with them through the same interface without having to worry about particular implementations details.